# Implementation of Partial Least Squares (PLS)?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I'm looking for a PLS implementation for Wolfram *Mathematica*. I just can't seem to find any implementation for it - do you know one? In general, I'm a bit confused that there exist only so few third-party packages/libraries for *Mathematica* in general :(

For now I probably will just use RLink in *Mathematica* to be able to refer to [the R package pls](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pls/index.html) but a direct implementation in *Mathematica* would be nicer for debugging and testing purposes...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this different from "Partial Sum of Squares" http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RegressionCommon/ref/PartialSumOfSquares.html

Comment: @bills yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression

Comment: well, the wiki page gives the algorithm and it looks straightforward. What have you tried?

Comment: @george2079 I haven't tried anything because I thought there would exist an implementation somewhere and if you're completely new to mathematica, it's not that easy to implement it and I'm sure it'll be prone to errors...

Comment: This would be a really nice application of `NestList`, if only I had time today.